# Initialize a list and find the mean of that list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop, initialization

My first function takes a list(L) of numbers and finds the average, it works perfectly.

```
def mean(L):
    x=sum(L)
    print x/float(len(L))
```

In my second function I am trying to ask the user to input 10 elements, initialize them into a list, and then use the first function mean(L) to find the average of the list:

```
def Values():
    L=[raw_input('enter element ') for i in range (0,10)]
    L=L[0::1]
    print L[0::1]
    print mean(L)
```

but i keep getting this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Off-topic: The canonical way to shallow copy a list is `L[:]`, not `L[0::1]`. The `0` and the `1` are implied, and on Python 2, you're actually using a slower interface (`__getitem__` with a `slice` instead of `__getslice__` with two `C` level `ssize_t`s) by explicitly passing the step. Also, you don't need to keep shallow copying it like that in the first place, since you're never mutating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string. Convert it to numeric type like `int`, `float`, ...:

```
L = [float(raw_input('enter element ')) for i in range (3)]
```

The function `mean` currently print the result. It's better to make it `return` the result so that `print mean(L)` will print the result instead of `None`.